# Looping with setLayoutParams - ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, android-layout

**-UPDATE-**

I have done as Agarwal suggested, and now have this error:

```
04-21 11:42:01.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1456): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
```

I am using this code to dynamically set the width of 15 Buttons. And, you guessed it, it doesn't work. The error happens in the `for` loop, but I'm not sure why.

```
    Button[] buttons = new Button[16];
    buttons[0] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.root2);
    buttons[1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.root3);
    /* blah blah blah */
    buttons[13] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.root15);
    buttons[14] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.root16);

    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(widthOfButtons,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    for(int x = 0; x < 16; x ++){
        buttons[x].setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
```

Thanks for any help. (And if anyone can think of a better way to fill the `buttons[]` variable, that would be very much appreciated.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int x = 0; x < 16; x ++){
        buttons[x].setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
```

the above loop repaeat for 16 times and you had instilized only 15 buttons either add a button or change x < 15.
if you change x< 15 then also change the below

Button[] buttons = new Button[15];

Comment: Thanks for that. I have changed it to `x < 15`, and now have a new error. Would you mind having a look? I have updated the question.

Comment: I was opening the array too much wasn't I, but I'm still getting the problem. Thanks for all your help though.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it using this:

```
LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(widthOfButtons,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    for(int x = 0; x < 15; x ++){
        buttons[x].setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
```

Getting `LayoutParams` from `LinearLayout`.